# Rails 3 where with multiple params

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause, parameters

I need to build a dynamic sql queue with 2 incoming params. It is easy when both params are defined.

```rails
MyClass.where(:column1 => param[:first], :column2 => params[:second])
```

but when for example `param[:first] = 0` I want to select all(not null) fields for this column(so when both params are = 0 it would be equal to `select * from tablename`). Tried this syntax:

```rails
MyClass.where(:column1 => param[:first], :column2 => !nil)
```

but it gives me wrong output. Any suggestions how to elegantly resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `?:` operator inside `where`:

```
MyClass.where(params[:first] ? {:column1 => params[:first]} : "column1 IS NOT NULL")
       .where(params[:second] ? {:column2 => params[:second]} : "column2 IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `MyClass.where('column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL').where({:column1 => params[:first], :column2 => params[:second]}.delete_if{|k,v| v.nil?})`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work from what I've found.  It appears to work in the rails console and considering active record alows active chaining:

```
MyClass.where(:column1 => params[:first], :column2 => params[:second]).where("column1 is NOT NULL").where("column2 is NOT NULL")
```